# Random numbers double type

Tags: c++

I had an exercise in my book which made me to puzzle the answer by a long series of attempts which took me hours to configure out. I'm new to c++, and programming at all, which makes me lack of knowledge(actually I'm learning at home by the book). So i got a couple of questions which i hope you could answer them and "asset" my brains on the right place.

Before the questions, the exercise was :

> "Write a random-number generator that returns a random floating point
>   number between 0.0 and 1.0. (Hint: Call rand, cast the result r to type
>   double by using static_cast(r), and then divide by the highest value
>   in the int range, RAND_MAX.) Make sure you declare the function with the
>   double return type.".

The questions:

1. what is the main function/idea that stands behind the `srand(time(nullptr))`?
   I keep getting a warning of c4244 ('argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int'). I was searching the answer and I figured out the problem is in the `srand` command... please somebody can explain it?
2. I'm not truly clear about the `static_cast` and all the other 3 casting types . I know that in the `static_cast` i can define a new enum type from the parentheses to the braces from the left: `static_cast<double>(r)`. But, what is the limit/definition of each cast(`dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast`)? When do i use them?
3. I figured out that i must declare a double before the (`RAND_MAX`) statement, but i have no idea why it must be double and not int or float? What is the main idea that stands behind the `RAND_MAX`?

This is the code that i wrote(note: I'm using `#include "stdafx.h"` pre header just in case of... while in the book there is nothing mentioned about it):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

double rand_(int r);

int main() {
    int n;
    double r;

    cout << " choose a number: ";
    cin >> n;

    srand(time(nullptr));

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        r = rand_(n) ;
        cout << r << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

double rand_(int r) {
    static_cast<double>(r);

    return rand() / double(RAND_MAX);

}
```

If you notice any "clearance" mistakes of basic coding please correct me.

Thanks for all who answer and support this post. Hope in future could do the same.

Comment: You've misread the instructions. The function is not supposed to take a parameter. "Call rand, cast the result r to type double". `r` just symbolises the result of calling `rand`.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` suggests your book is a bit outdated. That refers to the old random number generator inherited from C. C++ has a much-improved `<random>` library. Especially relevant here, that includes a `std::uniform_real_distribution`.

Comment: 1. srand(...) is a seed function. It gets current system time which is different every time you call it. rand() is just an algorithm, that gives you a point of a pseudo random series. If you dont have seed, you will always get the same random series each time you restart your system.
3. Assume n < RAND_MAX, the 0 < n/RAND_MAX < 1

Comment: Note: in Visual studio, you have to call srand twice discarding the first call.

Comment: Please do not ask three different questions in the same, uh, *question*.

Comment: @molbdnilo No, i read carefully the instructions(as i always do) and i wrote this on my "draft". The real problem was while i started to write the code.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MSalters Ill mark this in mind, thanks.

Comment: @NgoThanhNhan From the previous exercises i learned that "srand() ..." indeed is a seed function which derives the "time value" from the system --> to the code. Can you tell me how many cases there are , of writing in rand() algorithm(im only familiar with the time(nullptr))?.

Comment: @FelipeLopez Dear Felipe, Im sorry but i misunderstood you ? only in Visual or there another environments?Why is it differs? Why i need to discard the first call? Thank you

Comment: @flyx                   No Problem, Ill try my best :)

Comment: @Mabadai sorry I meant rand(),


The implementation of rand() in Visual Studio has a flaw -- the first random number generated doesn’t change much for similar seed values. This means that when using time() to seed your random number generator, the first result from rand() won’t change much in successive runs.

However, there’s an easy fix: call rand() once and discard the result. Then you can use rand() as normal in your program.

Source: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/59-random-number-generation/

Comment: @FelipeLopez Thanks for your time and explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
srand(time(nullptr));
```

its used to initialise pseudo random number generator, with seed, obtained from current time (to get different rundom numbers each time you run your ptogramm).
srand() accepts unisgned int parameter, time() return time_t, so here is your warning about conversion.

```
rand() / double(RAND_MAX)
```

rand() return integer value, RAND_MAX is integer constant, so to get floating point division, instead of integer division RAND_MAX is conversed to floating point type.

As for when to use which type of cast its bit to broad, and I'm pretty sure you can find info about every particular cast on SO or cppreference.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, you totally organized my mind for this issue.